# Datas from a char array well displayed while iterating to display byte by byte but not otherwise

Tags: c++, pointers, char, cout

I have a problem that I don't understand in C++:
 I got a unsigned char* as a result from a method call. if I iterate the char* to display the datas everything is fine, but when I just print the datas there are not the same values displayed.

Here is my code sample:

```
unsigned char returning[32];
for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
    returning[i] = result[i];
    std::cout << returning[i];//return the good values
}
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << returning << "\n";
//the first one are the good values, and then there are wrong
```

Someone could explain me this strange behavior?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What output are you getting? Is the array zero-terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
unsigned char returning[33];
returning[32] = '\0';
```

fixed.

Explanation:

The first loop will print every value in "returning". The second piece of code will only return the values until it hits a value which is zero. And then it stops, because a zero in a char array is interpreted as an end of line character.

Alternatively, if the there is no zero in "returning" anywhere, the second piece of code will continue to write random values until it does hit a zero.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in `returning` array, you are just assigning values till 31st index which is wrong. Last byte of that should be null terminated `\0`.

`std::cout << returning[i]` This statement will read the ASCII value from that particular and it will print the corresponding character.

`std::cout << returning` But this statement will keep on reading bytes till it reaches `\0`. In your case `returning` array is not `NULL` terminated. So in this buffer overflow will happen and it will print first 32 byte proper characters and then it will start printing some other characters(may be not readable formal also). If `\0` never comes in the further bytes  then it will surely tries to go beyond that segment at that time application will crash.